# Angular replace directive for SVG (result is in DOM but not displayed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I have a set of Angular directives for drawing svg charts, which I need to use. The exact directive name depends on the type of the chart (i.e. 'barlineChart', 'bulletChart' etc.). To simplify things and not copypaste, I decided to create a 'wrapper' directive that let's you select the chart type.

If using the original directives, html looks the following way:

```
<g x-barline-chart
   x-chart-properties="{{component1.properties}}"></g>
<g x-bullet-chart
   x-chart-properties="{{component2.properties}}"></g>
```

With my new directive:

```
<g x-ng-repeat="component in chart.components"
   x-chart-type="{{component.chartType}}"
   x-chart-properties="{{component.properties}}"></g>
```

Directive code:

```
.directive('chartType', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            type : '@chartType'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            attributes.$set(scope.type, "");
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is the problem. The new element gets compiled, and if I inspect the DOM, I can see it is there with the new attribute added. However, it is not rendered and seems to not be using the new directive I just appended.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you need to call `scope.$apply()`?

Comment: Tried that. `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` already calls `$scope.$apply()`, but even if I wrap in timeout, that doesn't work. Not for svg, it seems.

Comment: I think you may need to put your `g` inside `div` and use your directive on this `div`. Then `$compile(element.contents())` will compile every elements inside this `div`. Now it seems your element has no children elements, so it has nothing to compile. It would be easier to help if you post a jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Keen to try and help but really need a jsfiddle or plunk to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use the pre link function of the directive (or maybe even the compile function) when you modify the DOM and angular needs to be aware of the new elements (ie: the injected elements contains angular code).

See https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/$compile

To change it to a pre-link, do the following:

```
.directive('chartType', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            type : '@chartType'
        },
        link: {
            pre : function (scope, element, attributes) {
                attributes.$set(scope.type, "");
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

If this doesn't work, then you might need to use the compile function instead. But I've done this kind of directive in the past and never needed to use the compile function, pre-link was alright for my case.